# Differences between Strapi and Netlify cms

Tags: mongodb, nuxt.js, netlify, strapi, jamstack

I am not that expert in the backend development and got a bit confused. If someone can share their ideas would be much appreciated.
I did before a blog/webpage using Nuxt and Netlify cms that worked good.It was deployed also in Netlify.
Now I am using Nuxt and strapi to create the same type( blog/webpage). It works in development. In production, I have to deploy it in Heroku right and then Netlify if I want to host it there.
My questions are:

Do I always need to use mongodb as a database? When using Netlify was not necessary. can someone explain why?Any other easy/free solution?

How this process all works?

Sorry if this is a simple question but honestly don't have many people around to ask it :)
Thank you

Comment: Strapi can use many different databases it does not have to be Mongo

Comment: Strapi is essentially a headless CMS which means they supply pure data only. Using that any client can build their own front end. Conventional CMS solutions works for web platforms only(in html). But headless CMSes can be integrated with d\f platforms. Even for RTF support they dont convert it to html rather special markups which can be markdown to native components respective to client platform